# Backup iPad to the USB HDD attached to MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad

My wife has a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017) with 256GB SSD.
She recently purchased a iPad Air 4 256 GB.

She (unsurprisingly) can't backup her iPad to the MacBook as it requires 60GB.

Is it possible to backup to a USB HDD?

If so how?

I finally got around to trying (realistically I was allowed to access my wife's laptop) the suggestion below. Unfortunately I can't seem to access the MobileSync directory.

I had previously checked on my iMac but I have disabled SIP.

Even using `sudo` won't let me access the directory and results in "operation not permitted" although most of the other directories are accessible.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete or rename the old backup folder located there: `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync`
2. Create new backup folder on your USB HDD
3. Create link by the following terminal command (replace *path* with the path to your new backup folder): `sudo ln -s "PATH" ~/Library/Application\Support/MobileSync/Backup`